# Autofill always ask for confirmation to store the credentials and doesn't associate existing credentials to the app

Tags: flutter, autofill

We are currently trying to save the login credentials in our flutter app. It works fine on android but seems to be broken on iOS. The following problems occur:

1. The keyboard overlay does not show the saved credentials but the possibility to open the password manager and you have to manually select the credentials. They are then entered correctly in the email and password field.
2. After every login a system overlay shows up and ask for confirmation to save the credentials even if they are already stored.
   The following is a minimal code snippet for the login form

```
  Container _buildLoginForm(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: AutofillGroup(
            onDisposeAction: AutofillContextAction.commit,
            child: Wrap(runSpacing: 10, children: [
              TextField(
                autofillHints: const <String>[AutofillHints.username], 
                decoration: getTextFieldDecoration("E-Mail"), 
                controller: _emailController),
              TextField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  autofillHints: const <String>[AutofillHints.password],
                  decoration: getTextFieldDecoration("Password"),
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  onEditingComplete: () => _handleLogin()),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => _handleLogin(),
                child: const Text("Login"),
              )
            ])));
  }
```

and the apple-app-site-association file

```
{
   "webcredentials":{
      "apps":[
         "<TeamID>.<AppID>"
      ]
   },
   "applinks":{
      "apps":[ ],
      "details":[
         {
            "appID":"<TeamID>.<AppID>",
            "paths":[ "*", "/" ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The server log shows that the apple-app-site-association file is accessed and the credentials are saved for the correct domain (they are even accessible on another login page in Safari browser).

We are using Flutter 3.10.6 (also tried 3.12.0) and iOS 15.7.7 on an old iPad Air2.

Is there something wrong with our code or the configuration?

We tried different combinations of configurations including another domain and appid. The credentials are always stored correctly but never associated back to the fields in the flutter app.

Comment: It's a flutter bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/116889